# Full Build in Websphere Commerce Solr is failing

Tags: java, solr, websphere-commerce

I have done the pre process for solr and while doing the full build, I get the below exception

```
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:43 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.util.SolrUtil makeDataImportNoCleanCommand(String, String, SolrServer, boolean)
FINE: url: /MC_10001_CatalogEntry_Unstructured_en_US/dataimport
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.util.SolrUtil makeDataImportNoCleanCommand(String, String, SolrServer, boolean)
SEVERE: error: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper printException(Logger, Exception)
FINER: ENTRY java.util.logging.Logger@ea539abf org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /MC_10001_CatalogEntry_Unstructured_en_US/dataimport Indexing failed
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: ENTRY _INFO_DI_BUILDINDEX_EXIT_FAILURE_UNRECOVERABLE_ERROR [Ljava.lang.Object;@3654fda4
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: RETURN Data import process was unsuccessful. An unrecoverable error has occurred.
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper printException
INFO: Data import process was unsuccessful. An unrecoverable error has occurred.
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /MC_10001_CatalogEntry_Unstructured_en_US/dataimport Indexing failed
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.util.SolrUtil.makeDataImportNoCleanCommand(SolrUtil.java:571)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.fullDataImport(DataImportProcessorMain.java:1941)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.executeDIH(DataImportProcessorMain.java:1045)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.process.DataImportProcessorMain.main(DataImportProcessorMain.java:463)

Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: ENTRY _INFO_DI_BUILDINDEX_DEBUG_WARNING [Ljava.lang.Object;@70828786
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper getLocalizedMessage(String, Object[])
FINER: RETURN For more information to debug, open the trace under the Solr server for more details and run the utility again.
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper printException
INFO: For more information to debug, open the trace under the Solr server for more details and run the utility again.
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportHelper printException(Logger, Exception)
FINER: RETURN
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportDatabaseHelper deleteFromDeltaTable(Set, Long, Long, Connection)
FINER: ENTRY [CatalogGroup, CatalogEntry] 10,001 -1
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportDatabaseHelper getTemplateSQL(String)
FINER: ENTRY DELETE_TI_DELTA_CATGROUP_BY_MC_ID_AND_CATGROUP_ID
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportDatabaseHelper getTemplateSQL(String)
FINER: RETURN DELETE FROM TI_DELTA_CATGROUP WHERE MASTERCATALOG_ID = ? AND CATGROUP_ID = ?  AND (ACTION = 'P' OR ACTION = 'B' OR ACTION ='Z')
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.util.DataImportDatabaseHelper deleteFromDeltaTable(Set, Long, Long, Connection)
FINE: DELETE FROM TI_DELTA_CATGROUP WHERE MASTERCATALOG_ID = ? AND CATGROUP_ID = ?  AND (ACTION = 'P' OR ACTION = 'B' OR ACTION ='Z')
Mar 27, 2017 1:27:44 PM com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.config.util.DataImportPreProcessConfigHelper isJ2SE
FINER: ENTRY
```

It is not able to recognize IOUtils which is already available as part of the jar.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Check your SRCHCONFEXT and SRCHCONF tables in the CONFIG column to make sure you are pointing to the correct SOLR server location.

Comment: Could you add the source regarding these settings?